# How to publish/subscribe JMS message between two applications?

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic

I have two Java standalone applications. I want to send message from one application and asynchronously receive message by two clients: one is in the same application as the sender. The other is in a different application. Both are connected with ActiveMQ broker. But I can only see that the first client got the message while the other didn't get the message. What is the general approach to connect two applications by JMS? I think I must have some unclear concept about JMS. I looked up around but couldn't figure out how to set up my Spring bean configuration file to publish/subscribe message between two Java applications.

Here is my sender's bean configuration file in the first application and also the first listener's bean which is in the same application:

```
<bean id="customerMessageSender" class="com.example.message.CustomerStatusSender">
    <property name="jmsTemplate" ref="jsmTemplateBean" />
    <property name="topic" ref="topicBean" />
</bean>

<bean id="jsmTemplateBean" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactoryBean"/>
    <property name="pubSubDomain" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="topicBean" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTopic">
    <constructor-arg value="CustomerStatusTopic" />
</bean>

<bean id="connectionFactoryBean" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616" />
</bean>

<bean id="customerStatusListener" class="com.example.message.CustomerStatusListener" />


<bean id="listenerContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactoryBean" />
    <property name="destination" ref="topicBean" />
    <property name="messageListener" ref="customerStatusListener" />
</bean>
```

Here is the bean configuration file for the second listener which is in a different application:

```
<bean id="topicBean" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTopic">
    <constructor-arg value="CustomerStatusTopic" />
</bean>

<bean id="connectionFactoryBean" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616" />
</bean>

<bean id="anotherCustomerStatusListener" class="com.mydomain.jms.CustomerStatusMessageListener" />

<bean id="listenerContainer"
    class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactoryBean" />
    <property name="destination" ref="topicBean" />
    <property name="messageListener" ref="anotherCustomerStatusListener" />
</bean>
```

As you can see, both `customerStatusListener` bean and `anotherCustomerStatusListener` bean subscribe to the `topicBean`. But only the first listener gets the message since it is in the same application as the sender while the second does not. What is the general principle to connect two Java applications by JMS so that message can be sent/received between two separate applications?

**Edit: I can't add the following listener bean in the first XML file since the class `CustomerStatusMessageListener` is in a different application therefore is not visible in the classpath of the first (sender's) application.**

```
<bean id="anotherCustomerStatusListener" class="com.mydomain.jms.CustomerStatusMessageListener" />
```

**Edit again: The following is the second listener in the second application which is separate from the first application. It contains a `main` method to instantiate the listener bean (jms-beans.xml is the bean configuration file for the second listener as listed above).**

```
public class CustomerStatusMessageListener implements MessageListener {
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Subscriber 2 got you! The message is: "
                        + ((TextMessage) message).getText());
            } catch (JMSException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Message must be of type TextMessage");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("jms-beans.xml");
        CustomerStatusMessageListener messageListener = (CustomerStatusMessageListener) context.getBean("anotherCustomerStatusListener");
        context.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your understanding of JMS is correct.  If you want two listeners to receive the same message, then a topic is the way to do it.  It shouldn't matter if one listener is running in the same VM as the sender and the other one is not.  Without seeing your code, your Spring configuration also looks correct.   That leaves a few more things to check:

- Are both listeners running on the same host?  That is, is `localhost` one place for one of the listeners and a different place for the other listener?
- Is your second listener running at the time the message was sent?  If your second listener isn't active when the message is sent, it won't see if it starts later, unless you're using durable topics **AND** your subscriber has connected to the broker at least once.

Based on your comments, the second item is where you are having problems.

This [blog post](http://stefanlearninglog.blogspot.com/2009/07/persistent-jms-topics-using-activemq.html) tells how to set up durable topics (and persist messages if you need messages to persist through broker restarts).  Basically, add this configuration to your message listeners:

```
<property name="subscriptionDurable" value="true">
<property name="clientId" value="Some_unique_id">
<property name="durableSubscriptionName" value="Some_unique_id">
```

The client id and durable subscription name must be different for every subscriber, so your first listener would have something like:

```
<bean id="listenerContainer"
class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactoryBean" />
        <property name="destination" ref="topicBean" />
        <property name="messageListener" ref="anotherCustomerStatusListener" />
        <property name="subscriptionDurable" value="true">
        <property name="clientId" value="listener1">
        <property name="durableSubscriptionName" value="listener1">
</bean>
```

And second should have:

```
      <bean id="listenerContainer"
           class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
           <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactoryBean" />
           <property name="destination" ref="topicBean" />
           <property name="messageListener" ref="anotherCustomerStatusListener" />
           <property name="subscriptionDurable" value="true">
           <property name="clientId" value="listener2">
           <property name="durableSubscriptionName" value="listener2">
       </bean>
```

Note that you **must start your second listener at least once** to register itself with the broker so the broker knows its clientId and will store messages for it, but you can then shut it down and start it later to get any messages it missed while it was down.

If your listener stays down for a long time on a high-volume system, the broker will store all messages for it, which might eventually fill the disk or slow the broker down.  See the [ActiveMQ documentation for automatically removing durable messages](http://activemq.apache.org/manage-durable-subscribers.html).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. For the first item you pointed out, both listeners run on the same host and same JVM. For the second item, the second listener is not running when the message is sent by the first application, i.e., the second application is not active when the first application is sending the message to the ActiveMQ Topic. So how to make the second listener retrieve the message after it starts up? My original thought was: JMS allows any message listener to get message even after being offline for a while. Is that true?

Comment: Also the way I ran the two applications is: I have two `static main()` methods in the two applications. I ran the first `main()` and saw the first listener got the message. Then I ran the second `main()` but the second listener didn't get the message. Should I put the two applications on the same web server and let the server serve as the trigger point of the message sending/receiving instead of running the two applications as standalone Java application using two `main()` methods?

Comment: Sounds like you need durable topics.  I've updated my answer with info about setting up durable topics in ActiveMQ.  Whether you decide to run your code as a standalone java app or in a server doesn't matter to the JMS container as long as either solution doesn't have an extended downtime.  You should let the other requirements of your system drive this part of the architecture.

Comment: I've added the durable topics in my bean configuration for both listeners. But I still don't see the second listener got the message. Only the first listener got the message. I looked at the ActiveMQ web admin and it only shows the first listener in the Durable Topic Subscribers. I've added the second listener code in my original post. I just ran the `main()` method in the second listener as a Java application. Is it the right way to get it registered with ActiveMQ and get the message?

Comment: Your main is instantiating the spring context, and then exiting right away.  I doubt that is enough time for the listener to receive a message, and might not even be enough time for it to register with ActiveMQ.  Try keeping your second listener alive for a longer time with a few tens or so seconds of `Thread.sleep()` before you close the spring context and exit main.

Comment: OK, I finally got it working after I added `Thread.sleep(100)` before closing the Spring bean context. The interesting part is: I need to add some waiting time (100 msec in my case) in order for listener 2 to get the message from the ActiveMQ broker. What is the main cause of this latency between the sender/ActiveMQ/receiver? In high volume message service, can ActiveMQ keep up with the incoming message and dispatch them at proper speed?

Comment: The most likely cause for the delay is the time in setting up the initial connection from the listener to the broker, plus whatever setup and validation the broker does before sending the message back.  Once your initial connection has been set up, you should see less latency between message generation and message consumption.  ActiveMQ claims 2000 messages/second in a situation similar to yours.  See http://activemq.apache.org/performance.html.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That really helps me to understand the underlying mechanism.